# Float left image with no space below

Tags: css, image

How can I float an image to the left with no space below?

I have used `float: left`.

[image: Example]

HTML

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
#container {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#container img {
  min-width: 33.33333333333%;
  max-width: 33.33333333333%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/110/110/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
</div>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make them all the same height? I'm not sure it's clear what you're actually asking. [Look here for tips on asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What is your requirement? The question is very vague.

Comment: Seems as if you are asking for a column/masonry layout. There is a lot of information on this online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap images in columns, like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/wd9gL7j2/4/)

```
<div class = "container">
 <div class="column">
  <img src = "http://placehold.it/200x300">
  <img src = "http://placehold.it/200x200">
 </div>  
 <div class="column">
  <img src = "http://placehold.it/200x400">
  <img src = "http://placehold.it/200x200">
 </div>
 <div class="column">
  <img src = "http://placehold.it/200x500">
  <img src = "http://placehold.it/200x200">
 </div>    
</div>
```

css

```
.container{
 width: 100vw;
 position: relative; 
}
.column {
  float:left;
  width:33.333333%;
}    
.column img{
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

if you need to apply with no divs inside the container, I would recommend Roy's answer